# (express.js) empty cookie returned even after setting one via setHeader function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

**client:**

```html
<a href="http://localhost:3001/user/login">Login</a>
```

**server:**

```js
const token = jwt.sign({ broadcasterId: user.twitchId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

res.writeHead(301, {
    "Location": "http://localhost:3000",
    "Set-Cookie": [`jwt=${token}; HttpOnly`],
});
res.end();
```

expected the code above to return a cookie along with the response, but no cookies set on client.

Using express.js for server (port 3001) and react for client (port 3000).

[image]

I don' know why, but calling the api directly from the browser (http://localhost:3001/user/login) actually contains a desired jwt cookie.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cookie with flags `SameSite=None; Secure`

```
   "Set-Cookie": [`jwt=${token}; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure`],
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none

also use `res.set(field [, value])` to set cookies headers.

Comment: I actually tried without `HttpOnly` option and the cookie storage was still empty.

afaik, `HttpOnly` option only blocks you from accessing it via console and it should still be showing on storage

Comment: mm.. no luck even with `SameSite=None; Secure` options. Looks like I am missing some core parts :/

Comment: what version of express are you using?